# Text comparison application

Tags: applications, macos

I'm looking for a simple text comparison tool. Something which just compares two quick text, I don't care about file comparison, just quick text side by side comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [**TextWrangler**](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/), there is a command "Compare Two Front Documents". TextWrangler is not just a simple text comparison tool, but it's free, and if you need to edit text anyway, it's a useful feature.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I actually use vim as my main text editor and I forget about vimddiff :)